# Scala web services

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatra

What are my options for frameworks for creating high performance web services using Scala, without too much fat? I am a total newbie at Scala and IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm looking at it for some future development -- for now, I'm in learning mode, and I've managed to get things working with the Play 2.0 framework, but not appropriate for my needs.

Coming from ruby's Sinatra, I found Scalatra, but honestly I got totally confused at trying to get it to work with INtelliJ IDEA 12 on Windows. Is there a tutorial that would help me create a debuggable Scalatra project in this IDE, on Windows? The instructions here (http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/ide-support.html) left me needing more -- I don't even fully understand where scalatra fits into those instructions. Or how I go from those instructions to creating an actual project and run configuration.

Are there other frameworks like Scalatra (in spirit) I could use, if I do not need to do any UI work for now?

Comment: `Play 2.0 framework, but not appropriate for my needs` out of curiosity can you explain this :)

Comment: Not as much as  "not apropriate" but rather that I'm looking for something ultra lean in the spirit of a micro framework. Seems to me PLay would be great for writing interactive web sites, but that's not what I'm writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked is instructions for after you've already created a basic Scalatra template project via the command line (following the instructions here: http://www.scalatra.org/getting-started/)

You can then use 'sbt gen-idea' to create the .iml project file, then use that to import the project into Intellij (from File -> Import Project).

Comment: Thanks, I am tentatively marking this as an answer since it clarifies much, but my next hurdle is that I do not have a sbt (exe?) anywhere on windows. I did install the plugin, or so I think I did. But I will spend some more time with this new understanding. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: I did manage to get this forward using the SBT plugin and running it inside the console (I'm sorry, but this whole thing is a mess, especially when you start dealing with proxies!) but now I'm stuck at the giter8 (g8) part....

Comment: I also had trouble using g8 through a proxy. In the end I had to create the project outside the network and bring it in on a USB. After setting up you don't need g8 anymore.

Comment: I used Proxifier (http://www.proxifier.com/) to get around the proxy issues. The whole setup is still a mess, but at least I have it working. So many moving parts, and so easy for things to go bad.  I hope to find an OSS version of Proxifier though, I'd like to keep it around and be able to trust it. :)